# GXT: Different context menu for the columns of a tree grid

Tags: gwt, contextmenu, gxt, treegrid

I'm using GXT 3.1.4 with GWT 2.7.0 and I'm in the process of migrating a tree grid from GXT 2 to GXT 3. This tree grid displayed a different context menu for each column and also the menu contained different entries depending on the value displayed in the cell or some other properties of the model.

This was done by overriding the onMouse method of the column config that was used there, where we had easy access to the model and the menu for that grid was constructed and set inside that method. How can this be achieved in GXT3? I need to easily identify the cell that was right clicked and access the model behind.

Thanks.